# How to solve Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/core-js/map' in Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, babeljs

I am using Material UI for React, I updated the Material-UI to the latest version and it is giving me following error

> ../node_modules/material-ui/styles/withStyles.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/core-js/map' in
>
> 'C:\Users\User\Documents\code\react\node_modules\material-ui\styles'

I downgraded to the previous version of the Material-UI as well, worked around with installing the correct version of babel as well but still having the same issue.

Here is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.1.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^3.0.0-alpha.30",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "material-auto-rotating-carousel": "^3.0.1",
    "material-auto-rotating-carousel-refurb": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-animated-slider": "^1.1.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-motion": "^0.5.2",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.1.49",
    "react-router": "^3.2.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.2",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.3",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  }
```

Comment: What is the stack trace of the error? You've left out the most important part.

Comment: The material-ui beta package is deprecated and buggy, hence the issue here. You should change to a stable version of @material-ui/core - https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9026

Comment: Yeah, your error mentions `material-ui` but your `dependencies` reference `@material-ui/core` so this question has mixed messages. If you're using `material-ui` them your deps are wrong, and you need to downgrade to a stable version.

Comment: @ravibagul91 I have followed this and only using material-ui/core not material-ui. You can see in my package.json dependencies as well

Comment: There must be something in your system still referencing `material-ui` or else the error message wouldn't be mentioning it.

Comment: I have checked manually, is there a way to check automatically, perhaps the line number ?

Answer (score 5):

I figured this issue out by adding a resolution in my `package.json`, but it only will work if you use `yarn` instead of `npm`.

**my fix** (if you use yarn)

```js
// in your package.json
...
"resolutions": {
    "material-ui/@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.42"
}
...
```

Why does it work?, because `@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.42` still requires `core-js` as a dependency, in specific it requires `core-js ^2.5.3`

**Alternative fix**

If you are not using `yarn` and rather `npm`, you can add `@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.42` as a devDependency and it should be work fine as well.

I left the link to [`yarn resolutions`](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/), because it might be interesting for you.

Comment: unfortunately this messes up some apps and is not possible to use with all setups. (other dependencies)